# Typescript is slower than javascript when using sequelize?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js

I am migrating a web app from javascript to typescript. And I have noticed that the query results are a bit slower sometimes as compared to javascript. It is not consistent though.

I have two tables - User and Team. One user can have many teams. So it is hasMany and belongsTo association between them.

Team Model

```
import {Model, Table, Column, Default} from 'sequelize-typescript';
@Table
export class Team extends Model {

  @Column name!: string;
  @Default(true)
  @Column isActive!: boolean;
}
```

User Model

```
import {Model, Table, Column, Default,DataType} from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table
export class User extends Model {

  @Column firstName!: string;
  @Column lastName!: string;
  @Column email!: string;
  @Default(true)
  @Column isActivated!: boolean;
  @Column source!: string;
  @Column(DataType.JSON)
  profileData: string;
  @Column(DataType.JSON)
  settings: string;
  @Column(DataType.JSON)
  paymentDetails: string;
}
```

The association

```
Team.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "fk_ownerId", as: 'Owner' });
User.hasMany(Team, { foreignKey: "fk_ownerId", as: 'OwnedTeams' });
```

Here are my results

```
30k records

typescript
user ins query: 2.955s
user query: 2.134s

javascript
user ins query: 3.785s
user query: 1.947s

50k records

typescript
team ins query: 4.621s
team query: 2.601s

javascript
team ins query: 4.352s
team query: 2.340s
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2015"
        ]
    }
}
```

I am running `tsc --build` to generate the build.
Is there anything that I have been doing wrong ?

Comment: You're aware that TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, right? Why would it be faster?

Comment: yes. so it is fine to have this much difference in performance ? I thought I am missing out on any configuration.